# Chrome LiveReload extension / guard-livereload disconnecting browser

Tags: google-chrome, guard, livereload

I have a problem with connecting guard-livereload to browser. Everytime i try to enable LiveReload plugin it connects to the browser and disconnect it automatically. LiveReload then shows this:

http://img21.imageshack.us/img21/2265/bugqf.png

my Guardfile:

```
    guard 'livereload' do
        watch(%r{.+\.(html|css|js)$})
    end
```

console output:

```
PS D:\workspace\xampp\htdocs\lab\test-menu> guard
04:22:12 - INFO - Guard uses TerminalTitle to send notifications.
04:22:12 - INFO - Guard is now watching at 'D:/workspace/xampp/htdocs/lab/test-menu'
04:22:12 - INFO - LiveReload 1.6 is waiting for a browser to connect.
[Listen warning]:
  Missing dependency 'wdm' (version '~> 0.1')!
  Please run the following to satisfy the dependency:
    gem install --version '~> 0.1' wdm

  For a better performance, it's recommended that you satisfy the missing dependency.
  Listen will be polling changes. Learn more at https://github.com/guard/listen#polling-fallback.

[1] guard(main)> 04:22:17 - INFO - Browser connected.
04:22:18 - INFO - Browser disconnected.
04:22:21 - INFO - Browser connected.
04:22:22 - INFO - Browser disconnected.
04:22:24 - INFO - Browser connected.
04:22:25 - INFO - Browser disconnected.
```

Versions:

- guard: 1.7.0
- livereload: 2.0.9
- chrome: 26.0.1410.64 m
- windows: 8

Sorry for my poor English. Thanks, Adam.

Comment: i resolved that missing dependency but it still not working actualy it isnt showing Browser connected or browser disconnected

Answer (score 0):

Once you're already using Guard and livereload, you might use rack-livereload gem in alternative to the plugin. It might look a little hard to configure, but if you follow the instructions in its Github page, you'll be livereloading right away.

Its avaliable at:
https://github.com/johnbintz/rack-livereload

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem just now after switching from Chromium to Chrome and fixed it by doing

```
gem install guard guard-livereload
```

Not sure what the problem was - I also had some dependency warnings like you and they are still appearing

```
WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset:
      thor (>= 0.14.6)
      ffi (>= 0.5.0)
WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs.
Please report a bug if this causes problems.
```

But anyway now the browser connects without disconnecting right away.

**Note:** I'm using Ruby setup via [RVM](https://rvm.io/).

Comment: Was there any resolution to the warning you are receiving?  Having the same issue.

Comment: I don't know. On the machine I am on right now, guard is running without any warnings. Since they weren't causing me any issues, I didn't really pay them any heed afterwards.